# Strange openssl build error in android ndk

Tags: android-ndk, openssl

I am facing some build error for OpenSSL in android ndk. The error is

```
make: *** No rule to make target `/home/computer/openssl-android-master/crypto/cryptlib.c', needed by `obj/local/armeabi/objs/crypto/cryptlib.o'.  Stop.
```

I don't know where it is targeted.

Comment: It seems like that this file /home/dipanjan/openssl-android-master/crypto/cryptlib.c missing.

Comment: Solved that by cleaning the outputs (binary libs) as android ndk r8e sometimes does not clean when building.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is to clarify the users about android ndk r8e- that android ndk r8e sometimes does not clean the previously build files, so one should check and delete the binary files.